# Trigger Builder fails after building 1 trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following scripts in Google Sheets.  I need to build triggers that will email certain information every weekday.  According to the Execution Transcript,  buildTriggers() fails before it's even finished building the first trigger, displaying the error, "Execution failed: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added."   There is only one other trigger in the script and it's assigned to another file, so I'm well clear of the 20 triggers/script quota.  I even tried reducing it to one trigger, making it simply daily, but it still failed at the same point.  Thank you in advance for anyone who has any ideas.

```
 function addTeamMember(){
   var tmSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
   var currRow = tmSheet.getLastRow() +1;
    if(tmSheet.getRange(1,100).getValue() == ""){
      buildTriggers()
      tmSheet.getRange(1, 100).setValue("Triggers Set")
    } 

 // a bunch of other stuff that isn't relevant here 
 }

 function buildTriggers(){

     ScriptApp.newTrigger("dailyEmail")
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
    .atHour(6)
    .create();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("dailyEmail")
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY)
    .atHour(6)
    .create();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("dailyEmail")
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
    .atHour(6)
    .create();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("dailyEmail")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
   .atHour(6)
   .create();

   ScriptApp.newTrigger("dailyEmail")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
   .atHour(6)
   .create();

 }
```

Comment: In the **Edit** menu of the code editor, choose **Current project's triggers**.  What do you see?  How many triggers are there?

Comment: Oh, wow, so many.  I guess I had been generating them every time I tested the script.  Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue. You may want to add the following to the beginning of the script while you are testing     var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

        for (var i=0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
       
       ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  
  
}